# How can I read a video file for use in openCV?

Tags: c++, video, opencv

I want to read a video file from an "avi file" and then enter it frame by frame to process it in openCV.
How can I do that?
Are there functions for that in openCV?  Should I use a video reading framwork?

What are good frameworks for reading video files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Working with video sequences**
Capturing a frame from a video sequence

Initializing capture from a camera:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); // capture from video device #0
```

Initializing capture from a file:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("infile.avi");
Capturing a frame:

IplImage* img = 0; 
if(!cvGrabFrame(capture)){              // capture a frame 
    printf("Could not grab a frame\n\7");
    exit(0);
}
img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture);// retrieve the captured frame
```

To obtain images from several cameras simultaneously, first grab an image from each camera. Retrieve the captured images after the grabbing is complete.

Releasing the capture source:

```
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

**Note** that the image captured by the device is allocated/released by the capture function. There is no need to release it explicitly.

Comment: You can also try http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/devframework.htm (ARToolkit Framework) but i will recommend OpenCV over it

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Questions:  what is the difference between cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame?  Does openCV support all types of videos or only avi?