# How to read avi file in mexopencv

Tags: matlab, opencv

As the title suggest I want to read `avi` files using `mexopencv`.I have got this far from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758627/how-can-i-read-a-video-file-for-use-in-opencv) for OpenCV. I want something similar for `mexopencv`.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("infile.avi");
Capturing a frame:

IplImage* img = 0; 
if(!cvGrabFrame(capture)){              // capture a frame 
    printf("Could not grab a frame\n\7");
    exit(0);
}
img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture);// retrieve the captured frame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C++ API, [`cv::VideoCapture`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) class can capture videos from both webcams and video files saved on disk:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture('file.avi');
for i=1:cap.get('FrameCount')
    img = cap.read();
    if isempty(img), break; end
    imshow(img)
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: Can I add it to mexopencv's github samples?

Comment: What does drawnow does?

Comment: [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) flushes the event queue letting MATLAB actually render the continuously updated image. Without it the loop will run all the way to the end before you see an image. This is similar to [`cv::waitKey`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) in OpenCV